# insert data into php table using form

Tags: php, mysql

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "******";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "*****";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {


$sql = "SELECT * from actor";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table border='0'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Nombre</th> <th>Apellidos</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>"."<td>".$row["cod_actor"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["nombre"]."</td>" ."<td>".$row["apellidos"]."</td>"."</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

this , when executed (along with some css on my end) results in this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/okrVe.jpg
What i want to do is a form that has 3 fields :

```
id: <input type="text" name="id"><br>
nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre">
apellidos: <input type="text" name="apellido"><br>
```

form this , i know i have to do this :

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
```

so i use what the user wrote on those fields to make the query :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO actores (id, nombre, apellido)
VALUES ('$id', '$nombre', '$apellido')";

if (mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) {
    echo "Insert successful";
} else {
    echo "there was an error " . mysqli_error($conexion);
}
```

Now , my issue is that those variables are empty when the users enters the form
i think i have to do something with isset but i tried doing an IF ,to no avail 
what would you recommend?

Also i'm trying to get the result of a query in an array i think i have to use

```
mysqli_fetch_array ( mysqli_result $result [, int $resulttype = MYSQLI_BOTH ] )
```

mixed with a While or something.

Comment: It could be a problem with your form, which is not shown. Probably best to post that here. You should have `<form method="post"..`, for example.

Comment: use prepared statement.It is much more safety.

Comment: what do you meant use prepared? where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['id'],$_POST['nombre'], $_POST['apellido'])) {

$id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$nombre=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nombre']);
$apellido=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['apellido']);

}

?>

<form action="" method="POST">

            <p>
                <input type="text" name="id" />
                <input type="text" name="nombre" />
                <input type="text" name="apellido" />


  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

            </p>

</form>
```